# How to use JQuery $.when to process ajax calls in order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use `$.when` in JQuery with chained promises to ensure my ajax requests are completed in the right order?

I have an array called `costArray` which is made up of a number of dynamic objects.  For each item in this array, I'll call an Ajax request called `GetWorkOrder` which returns a `WorkOrder` which is basically a table row element with the class `.workOrder` and appends it to the table with id `#tbodyWorkOrders`.

Once all the items in the array are processed, I use `$.when` to let me know when I can calculate the `SubTotal` of each `WorkOrder`.

My problem is that my `WorkOrder`s are being inserted in random orders, as the ajax requests are being processed async.  How can I ensure my ajax requests are processed and appended in the correct order?

```
i = 0;

$.each(costArray, function (key, value) {
var d1 = $.get('/WorkOrders/GetWorkOrder', { 'i': i }, function (html) {
    $('#tbodyWorkOrders').append(html);
    $('.workOrder').last().find('input').val(value.Subtotal);
});

$.when(d1).done(function () {
    SetSubtotal();
    i++;
});
```

Edit:

costArray is taken from an earlier ajax call and is an array of items that I am inserting into the table rows:

```
var costArray = JSON.parse([{"Trade":"Plasterer","Notes":"Test","Subtotal":"3781.00"}]);
```

The line:

```
$('.workOrder').last().find('input').val(value.Subtotal);
```

is one of many that takes the values from GetWorkOrder and puts them into the correct inputs, but I've left out the extra code for clarity

Comment: Consider including an integer indicating order in the closure of the success callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.when()` processes all the promises you pass it in parallel, not sequential (since the async operations have already been started before you even get to `$.when()`).

It will collect the results for you in the order you pass the promises to `$.when()`, but there is no guarantee about the execution order of the operations passed to it.

What I would suggest is that you collect all the results (in order), then insert them in order after they are all done.

I've tried to restructure your code, but it is not clear what items form `costArray` you want to pass to your Ajax call.  You weren't passing anything from `costArray` in your code, but the text of your question says you should be.  So, anyway, here's a structural outline for how this could work:

```
var promises = costArray.map(function (value, index) {
    // Fix: you need to pass something from costArray to your ajax call here
    return $.get('/WorkOrders/GetWorkOrder', { 'i': value });
});
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    // all ajax calls are done here and are in order in the results array
    // due to the wonders of jQuery, the results of the ajax call
    // are in arguments[0][0], arguments[1][0], arguments[2][0], etc...
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var html = arguments[i][0];
        $('#tbodyWorkOrders').append(html);
    }
    SetSubtotal();
});
```

Comment: Please use a different phrasing from "`$.when` processes the operations"

Comment: don't think `$.when` takes array as argument without using `apply()`

Comment: @charlietfl - corrected - you are right.  It would have been so easy for jQuery to just see if you were passing it an array and be smart about that.  I never understood why they didn't do that.

Comment: don't you also have to loop over `arguments` rather than results also? I agree they should upgrade it to make it simpler

Comment: @charlietfl - yes, correct again.  I have switched my own development over to Bluebird promises and this is a couple more reminders why.  `jQuery.when()` is kind of a pain to use with a variable number of promises.

Comment: I've made an edit which clarifies how I use the results, thank you for your solution so far, will give it a go

Comment: `arguments` is undefined.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk - Since every function has an `arguments` object and every `arguments` object has a `.length` property, the error you report is confusing.  Perhaps an error somewhere earlier in the code that manifests itself this way.  See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Comment: @Evonet - OK, I'm still not quite following what you're trying to do with the `costArray`.  Hopefully, you can adapt this general technique to your specifics.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh wow, hadn't even known about that. Today I learned.

Comment: One last question, not sure what you mean with "// Fix: you need to pass something from costArray to your ajax call here"?  All I need to send to the ajax call is the index (i)

Comment: @Evonet - I assumed you're trying to pass something from `costArray` to the ajax call.  If not, then you can ignore that comment, but you will need to make sure the arguments to the ajax call are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a function and recall it from your ajax success:

```
ajax(0);
function ajax(key) {
    $.get('/WorkOrders/GetWorkOrder', {'i' : key }, 
        function (html) {
            $('#tbodyWorkOrders').append(html);
            $('.workOrder').last().find('input').val(costArray[key].Subtotal);
            SetSubtotal();
            key++;
            if (key < costArray.length)
                ajax(key);
        });
}
```

**Edit:** On further consideration, while this is one way to do it, it entails the ajax calls executing only one at a time, which isn't very time efficient. I'd go with jfreind00's answer.